# Why Goroutine Can Get Scheduled After Busy Loop?

Tags: go, scheduling, goroutine

See these code below. **I am not doing this in any production,  just for studying purpose.**

I have heard from many posters that busy loop usually prevents from scheduling because they leave no chance for the go sheduler to scheduler. If this is true why deadloop() goroutine can gets scheduled??

I am using `golang 1.12` and testing on windows os.

```
func main()  {

    go deadloop()         // v1 -- keeps printing forever

    var i =1
    for {
        i++
    }
}

func deadloop() {
    i := 0
    for {
        fmt.Printf("from deadloop\n")
        i++
    }
}
```

update: 
I was confused so that I didn't say it in a clearer way for the problem. I change the contents today, but I still have same question.

Comment: The busy loop in main may not yield to other goroutines once it starts running.  Replace the busy loop with `select {}` to get the results you expect.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Cerise's answer, it's because the busy loop, the `for` loop inside your `main` function. If the purpose of the loop is to prevent `main` of exiting then don't use `for`, use `select` instead. See code below:

```golang
func main()  {
    go deadloop2()

    select { } // <----- here
}

func deadloop2() {
    i := 0
    for {
        fmt.Printf("from deadloop i=%d\n", i)
        i++
    }
}
```